# Misunderstanding of the word "span"?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. I once read in a paper that $\{\psi_{0}\}^{\perp} = \text{span}\{\psi_{1},\psi_{2},...\}$, but I do not see how this is true. Because $\text{span}\{\varphi_{0}\}$ is closed, then $\mathscr{H} = (\text{span}\{\varphi_{0}\})\oplus \{\varphi_{0}\}^{\perp}$ holds. Moreover, $\{\psi_{1},\psi_{2},...\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\{\varphi_{0}\}^{\perp}$, so that $\text{span}\{\psi_{1},\psi_{2},...\}$ is *dense* in $\{\varphi_{0}\}^{\perp}$. Hence, every $\psi \in \{\varphi_{0}\}^{\perp}$ can be written as a sequence of elements in $\text{span}\{\psi_{1},\psi_{2},...\}$ but it does not imply that $\psi$ itself is an element of the latter. Am I missing something? Maybe the paper was using the word span to mean:
$$\psi = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle \psi_{n},\psi\rangle \psi_{n}?$$
This is not why the word span mean typically, tho.

Comment: Yes, according to standard definition of span it is not true that $\{\psi_{0}\}^{\perp} = \text{span}\{\psi_{1},\psi_{2},...\}$

Comment: Yes they definitely don't mean the algebraic span, they mean its closure.

Comment: or they switched the $\bot$ symbol from right to left otherwise $\operatorname{span} \{\psi_1 , \psi_2, \dots\}^\bot = k \psi_0$ or maybe they forgot to put the closure?

Comment: Yes, in functional analysis, people are sometimes loose with the purely linear algebra terminology (eg basis, span, direct sum etc) because after they make the initial definitions they get tired of having to consistently clarify that they mean for instance a *Schauder basis* or a *topological direct sum* etc. Often one has to take closures, and this is one such example.